# TBB 3.5.2 fail to connect, but TBB 3.5.0 works, where is wrong?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows, pluggable-transports

Hi there I'm trying to update my TBB from 3.5.0 to 3.5.2 but is having issue connecting.

Here's what I did:

1. Download the TBB 3.5.2 using TBB 3.5.0 and verify the signature, it shows 
   Good signature from Erinn Clark and so on (sorry I don't know how to dump the text from windows XP's cmd window)
2. Run the install program and place TBB 3.5.2 to a folder different than TBB 3.5.0.
3. Start TBB 3.5.2 and specify the same bridge setting as TBB 3.5.0. (I just copy and pasted bridge address from TBB 3.5.0's torrc to the bridge setting window during startup.)

After clicking connect button, TBB 3.5.2 just stuck at 'connecting to a directory server' phase (the progress bar remained at 0% all the time) forever (all night long) and I can't establish connections.

I did a log dumping (sorry guys it was long and messy, I'll only give messages critical to the question), :

```
Feb 15 21:53:34.000 [info] or_state_load(): Initialized state
Feb 15 21:53:34.000 [debug] circuit_build_times_disabled(): CircuitBuildTime learning is not disabled. Consensus=0, Config=0, AuthDir=0, StateFile=0
Feb 15 21:53:34.000 [debug] circuit_build_times_disabled(): CircuitBuildTime learning is not disabled. Consensus=0, Config=0, AuthDir=0, StateFile=0
Feb 15 21:53:34.000 [info] circuit_build_times_parse_state(): Adding 0 timeouts.
Feb 15 21:53:34.000 [info] circuit_build_times_parse_state(): Loaded 0/0 values from 0 lines in circuit time histogram
Feb 15 21:53:34.000 [debug] circuit_build_times_disabled(): CircuitBuildTime learning is not disabled. Consensus=0, Config=0, AuthDir=0, StateFile=0
Feb 15 21:53:34.000 [info] or_state_save(): Saved state to "D:\My Documents\AXD\E352BDT\Tor Browser\Data\Tor\state"
Feb 15 21:53:34.000 [info] read_file_to_str(): Could not open "D:\My Documents\AXD\E352BDT\Tor Browser\Data\Tor\router-stability": No such file or directory
Feb 15 21:53:34.000 [info] tor_process_monitor_new(): Successfully opened handle to process 1788; monitoring it.
Feb 15 21:53:34.000 [info] cell_ewma_set_scale_factor(): Disabled cell_ewma algorithm because of value in Default value
Feb 15 21:53:34.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file D:\My Documents\AXD\E352BDT\Tor Browser\Data\Tor\geoip.
Feb 15 21:53:35.000 [info] geoip_load_file(): Failed to open GEOIP file C:\Documents and Settings\Anthrax.M062-27213162A6\Application Data\tor\geoip6.  
Feb 15 21:53:35.000 [info] crypto_global_init(): OpenSSL version matches version from headers (1000106f: OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014).
Feb 15 21:53:35.000 [info] crypto_global_init(): NOT using OpenSSL engine support.
Feb 15 21:53:35.000 [info] evaluate_evp_for_aes(): This version of OpenSSL has a known-good EVP counter-mode implementation. Using it.
Feb 15 21:53:36.000 [info] tor_tls_init(): OpenSSL OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014 looks like version 0.9.8m or later; I will try SSL_OP to enable renegotiation
Feb 15 21:53:36.000 [debug] mp_pool_new(): Capacity is 248, item size is 528, alloc size is 130944
Feb 15 21:53:36.000 [info] Bootstrapped 0%: Starting.
Feb 15 21:53:36.000 [info] read_file_to_str(): Could not open "D:\My Documents\AXD\E352BDT\Tor Browser\Data\Tor\cached-certs": No such file or directory
Feb 15 21:53:36.000 [info] read_file_to_str(): Could not open "D:\My Documents\AXD\E352BDT\Tor Browser\Data\Tor\cached-consensus": No such file or directory
Feb 15 21:53:36.000 [info] read_file_to_str(): Could not open "D:\My Documents\AXD\E352BDT\Tor Browser\Data\Tor\unverified-consensus": No such file or directory
Feb 15 21:53:36.000 [info] read_file_to_str(): Could not open "D:\My Documents\AXD\E352BDT\Tor Browser\Data\Tor\cached-microdesc-consensus": No such file or directory
Feb 15 21:53:36.000 [info] read_file_to_str(): Could not open "D:\My Documents\AXD\E352BDT\Tor Browser\Data\Tor\unverified-microdesc-consensus": No such file or directory
Feb 15 21:53:36.000 [info] tor_mmap_file(): Couldn't mmap file "D:\My Documents\AXD\E352BDT\Tor Browser\Data\Tor\cached-microdescs": 系统找不到指定的文件。


Feb 15 21:53:36.000 [info] read_file_to_str(): Could not open "D:\My Documents\AXD\E352BDT\Tor Browser\Data\Tor\cached-microdescs.new": No such file or directory
Feb 15 21:53:36.000 [info] microdesc_cache_reload(): Reloaded microdescriptor cache. Found 0 descriptors.
Feb 15 21:53:36.000 [info] tor_mmap_file(): Couldn't mmap file "D:\My Documents\AXD\E352BDT\Tor Browser\Data\Tor\cached-descriptors": 系统找不到指定的文件。


Feb 15 21:53:36.000 [info] tor_mmap_file(): Couldn't mmap file "D:\My Documents\AXD\E352BDT\Tor Browser\Data\Tor\cached-extrainfo": 系统找不到指定的文件。
```

and close to the end of log, it shows:

```
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server.
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [debug] channel_tls_connect(): In channel_tls_connect() for channel 00EA3BD0 (global id 0)
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [warn] We were supposed to connect to bridge '173.246.104.81:45698' using pluggable transport 'obfs3', but we can't find a pluggable transport proxy supporting 'obfs3'. This can happen if you haven't provided a ClientTransportPlugin line, or if your pluggable transport proxy stopped running.
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [debug] channel_change_state(): Changing state of channel 00EA3BD0 (global ID 0) from "opening" to "channel error"
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [info] circuit_handle_first_hop(): connect to firsthop failed. Closing.
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [info] circuit_build_failed(): Our circuit died before the first hop with no connection
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [info] connection_ap_fail_onehop(): Closing one-hop stream to '$0000000000000000000000000000000000000000/173.246.104.81' because the OR conn just failed.
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [debug] circuit_increment_failure_count(): n_circuit_failures now 1.
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [info] circuit_get_open_circ_or_launch(): No safe circuit (purpose 5) ready for edge connection; delaying.
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [info] connection_ap_make_link(): ... application connection created and linked.
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [debug] connection_add_impl(): new conn type Directory, socket -1, address 173.246.104.81, n_conns 6.
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [debug] fetch_bridge_descriptors(): ask_bridge_directly=1 (1, 1, 0)
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [debug] directory_initiate_command_rend(): anonymized 0, use_begindir 1.
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [debug] directory_initiate_command_rend(): Initiating server descriptor fetch
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [info] connection_ap_make_link(): Making internal direct tunnel to [scrubbed]:47456 ...
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [debug] connection_add_impl(): new conn type Socks, socket -1, address (Tor_internal), n_conns 7.
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [debug] circuit_get_open_circ_or_launch(): considering 1, $0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [debug] onion_pick_cpath_exit(): Launching a one-hop circuit for dir tunnel.
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [info] onion_pick_cpath_exit(): Using requested exit node '$0000000000000000000000000000000000000000~0000000000000000000 at 23.239.140.214'
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [debug] onion_extend_cpath(): Path is 0 long; we want 1
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [debug] onion_extend_cpath(): Chose router $0000000000000000000000000000000000000000~0000000000000000000 at 23.239.140.214 for hop 1 (exit is 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000)
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [debug] onion_extend_cpath(): Path is complete: 1 steps long
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [debug] circuit_handle_first_hop(): Looking for firsthop '23.239.140.214:47456'
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [info] circuit_handle_first_hop(): Next router is [scrubbed]: Not connected. Connecting.
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [debug] channel_tls_connect(): In channel_tls_connect() for channel 00EA3BD0 (global id 1)
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [warn] We were supposed to connect to bridge '23.239.140.214:47456' using pluggable transport 'obfs2', but we can't find a pluggable transport proxy supporting 'obfs2'. This can happen if you haven't provided a ClientTransportPlugin line, or if your pluggable transport proxy stopped running.
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [debug] channel_change_state(): Changing state of channel 00EA3BD0 (global ID 1) from "opening" to "channel error"
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [info] circuit_handle_first_hop(): connect to firsthop failed. Closing.
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [info] circuit_build_failed(): Our circuit died before the first hop with no connection
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [info] connection_ap_fail_onehop(): Closing one-hop stream to '$0000000000000000000000000000000000000000/23.239.140.214' because the OR conn just failed.
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [debug] circuit_increment_failure_count(): n_circuit_failures now 2.
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [info] circuit_get_open_circ_or_launch(): No safe circuit (purpose 5) ready for edge connection; delaying.
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [info] connection_ap_make_link(): ... application connection created and linked.
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [debug] connection_add_impl(): new conn type Directory, socket -1, address 23.239.140.214, n_conns 8.
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [debug] fetch_bridge_descriptors(): ask_bridge_directly=1 (1, 1, 0)
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [debug] directory_initiate_command_rend(): anonymized 0, use_begindir 1.
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [debug] directory_initiate_command_rend(): Initiating server descriptor fetch
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [info] connection_ap_make_link(): Making internal direct tunnel to [scrubbed]:52176 ...
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [debug] connection_add_impl(): new conn type Socks, socket -1, address (Tor_internal), n_conns 9.
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [debug] circuit_get_open_circ_or_launch(): considering 1, $0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [debug] onion_pick_cpath_exit(): Launching a one-hop circuit for dir tunnel.
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [info] onion_pick_cpath_exit(): Using requested exit node '$0000000000000000000000000000000000000000~0000000000000000000 at 54.226.153.254'
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [debug] onion_extend_cpath(): Path is 0 long; we want 1
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [debug] onion_extend_cpath(): Chose router $0000000000000000000000000000000000000000~0000000000000000000 at 54.226.153.254 for hop 1 (exit is 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000)
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [debug] onion_extend_cpath(): Path is complete: 1 steps long
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [debug] circuit_handle_first_hop(): Looking for firsthop '54.226.153.254:52176'
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [info] circuit_handle_first_hop(): Next router is [scrubbed]: Not connected. Connecting.
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [debug] channel_tls_connect(): In channel_tls_connect() for channel 00EA3BD0 (global id 2)
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [warn] We were supposed to connect to bridge '54.226.153.254:52176' using pluggable transport 'obfs2', but we can't find a pluggable transport proxy supporting 'obfs2'. This can happen if you haven't provided a ClientTransportPlugin line, or if your pluggable transport proxy stopped running.
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [debug] channel_change_state(): Changing state of channel 00EA3BD0 (global ID 2) from "opening" to "channel error"
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [info] circuit_handle_first_hop(): connect to firsthop failed. Closing.
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [info] circuit_build_failed(): Our circuit died before the first hop with no connection
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [info] connection_ap_fail_onehop(): Closing one-hop stream to '$0000000000000000000000000000000000000000/54.226.153.254' because the OR conn just failed.
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [debug] circuit_increment_failure_count(): n_circuit_failures now 3.
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [info] circuit_get_open_circ_or_launch(): No safe circuit (purpose 5) ready for edge connection; delaying.
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [info] connection_ap_make_link(): ... application connection created and linked.
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [debug] connection_add_impl(): new conn type Directory, socket -1, address 54.226.153.254, n_conns 10.
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [debug] fetch_bridge_descriptors(): ask_bridge_directly=1 (1, 1, 0)
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [debug] directory_initiate_command_rend(): anonymized 0, use_begindir 1.
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [debug] directory_initiate_command_rend(): Initiating server descriptor fetch
Feb 15 21:59:12.000 [info] connection_ap_make_link(): Making internal direct tunnel to [scrubbed]:52176 ...
```

I am not very techincal savvy, but judging from the fact that TBB 3.5.0 works fine, then the problem must have noting to do with hardware or network connection. Where is wrong?

PS: I'm using winXP SP3, Kapasky AV. I live in a country with heavy network censorship.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Dear user1176, Use TBB version 3.5.0 if it works and request new bridges. Try new bridges in the TBB version 3.5.2 and 3.5.0. Verify that new bridges work in both versions of TBB. Please report the result.

Comment: Ok. I started TBB 3.5.0 and fetched some fresh bridges, however, 3 attempts only net me some normal bridges(ones without obfs), is it safe to use them in my country (with heavy censorship of course) ? Should I proceed with your advice, Roya ? -----user1176

Comment: Dear user1176, try this "I need an alternative way of getting bridges!

Another way to find public bridge addresses is to send an email (from a gmail or a yahoo address) to bridges@bridges.torproject.org with the line 'get bridges' by itself in the body of the mail."

Comment: Dear User1176, Also, it might help to send an email to: "If your Tor doesn't work, you should email help@rt.torproject.org. Try including as much info about your case as you can, including the list of bridges you used, the bundle filename/version you used, the messages that Tor gave out, etc." They maybe able to provide additional help.

Comment: Ok. I tried those normal bridges on TBB 3.5.2. I was able to establish connection for a few minutes, then all of them will get blocked. Quitting TBB 3.5.2 and start it again yield the following message: Tor failed to establish a tor network connection. Network is unreachable [WSAENETUNREACH], guess it may has someting to do with new form of censorship? Also, when I want to mail help@rt.torproject.org, do I need to use gmail or yahoo mailbox?

Comment: Dear user1176, not as far as I know.

Comment: Dear user1176, It seems to me that if you can get new "obfs" bridges somehow, Tor may work for you.

Comment: Ok. Then I will try to get help from afromentioned help@rt.torproject.org. I am preparing screenshots and log files. Also I'll try to get bridges using email. But I need to ask that from the tor blog I learnt that some sort of 'scramblesuit' is being tested among relay runners, is it possible that most obfs relays are being upgraded and not available now? I tried a few more times with TBB 3.5.0, every time I get normal bridges instead of obfs bridges. Ok, I'm running those bundles again to get fresh logs and prepare my email. I'll post results when I'm ready.

Comment: No luck so far. I obtained 3 obfs3 bridges that is different from earlier ones. After trying them the problem persists. Since I need to wait for 3 hours to send request via email, I'll try to obtain as many obfs bridges as possible and try again. I already sent email with logs to help desk. I'm now waiting for results. Thank you Roya, your attention on this matter is greatly appreciated. I'll post results when help arrives or I've accumulated enough new obfs bridges to (hopefully) bypass the censorship.

Answer (score 2):

You need Pluggable Transport bundle to use obfuscated bridges. And you seems like using non-pt bundle (no yet 3.5.2-pt built).

Comment: Oh yes. It seems that I've made a mistake. SOrry guys, I think I'll need to wait for pt bundles. CASE CLOSED.

Comment: @user1176 Please accept the answer so Question can be marked as Resolved.